# Spanner enable optimistic locking

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

How can I enable optimistic locking for Spanner? Spanner released that feature in 1.44 when we can set optimistic locking for transaction.

Spanner released that feature in 1.44 when we can set optimistic locking for transaction. I add `ReadLockMode: spannerpb.TransactionOptions_ReadWrite_OPTIMISTIC` in my transaction but when executed, it said Optimistic Locking is not enable?

I think the query past in Spanner emulator but not actual instance

Is there a feature request and settings I should set up for my project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dang-dam-quang, feature is not yet GA'ed and hence it was not mentioned in the release notes too https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/releases/tag/spanner%2Fv1.44.0, we will communicate this in future releases when the feature will be GAed
Thanks

Comment: Hi Rahul, do you have any update when the feature will be GAed? Thanks.